# tabs full height in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Based on an [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSheXC?p=preview) I am trying to put tabs in panel body with a full size like the example that worked very well, but in my case I still have no full height tab content.
Can someone explain to me what is the problem?

Above the code : the example.js file is the same in the example

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, .tabset, .tab-content, .tab-pane, .tabbable {
       height:100%;
      }

     .panel-body .tab-content {
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        background:green;
      }
      .panel-body {
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;
      }

      .panel{
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"> Example

    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl"> 
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">
        Static content
    </tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are getting vertical scroll, is that your issue?

Comment: no my problem is that i dont have a full tab height (the green one)

Comment: could you elaborate more on it please?

Comment: if you open the http://plnkr.co/edit/sSheXC?p=preview and replace the code by my code above you can see that the height of the tab content isn't a full height

Answer (score 2):

You need to add height for the intermediary element `panel-wrapper` which doesn't have specified an `height` component, `height: inherit` will inherit height from the parent element `.panel` which would be `100%` and then the `panel-body` class can utilize get that `height`.

```
.panel-wrapper{
    height: inherit;
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E5lvM4?p=preview)

Comment: Pankaj Parkar thank u for your answer but when i try your solution i have this error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: @Devjava its working good on my end..you must have some other network issue

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add panel

just wrap tabset inside div with panel class like this

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">
        Static content
    </tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
        {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

height will be as you desired